# WSO2 Identity Password reset confirmation link not invalidating

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently with wso2 Identity service we are using when we send a password reset link the link is not expiring after used. Looking at the documentation at the newer versions of wso2 identity this should be expiring after being used it seems the confirmation code is not expiring and letting the user click the link multiple times.

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use?

Comment: Current version is 5.10.0

Comment: I tested the password recovery with 5.10.0 GA, but the confirmation codes were cleared from the IDN_RECOVERY_DATA table as soon as a new password is set.  Could you please add more information on how do you reproduce this?